# Notification Click display unique data issue

Tags: android, android-notifications

[Not able to identify id for item clicked on notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31836529/not-able-to-identify-id-for-item-clicked-on-notification/31836754#31836754) was for unique id which is working out well,now for the same even with different id when i click on notifications i get unique invoice id ,which i am passing to a webservice to get its invoice details,even though its fetching data for that id,the itemActivity page is showing previous details only,how will i update the page with new contents ?

Send Notification code is

```
public class SampleSchedulingService extends IntentService {
    public SampleSchedulingService() {
        super("SchedulingService");
    }
    List<GetReminder> newReminderList;
    int invoiceId=0;
    String remMes;
    InvoiceData1 data1;
    int  InvM_Id;

    public static final String TAG = "Scheduling Demo";
    // An ID used to post the notification.
    public static int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder;

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        // BEGIN_INCLUDE(service_onhandle)
        // The URL from which to fetch content.
        Log.d("MyService", "About to execute MyTask");
     //    
 newReminderList=WebService.invokeGetReminderWS("GetReminder",41);

        if(newReminderList!=null){
         for(int i=0;i<newReminderList.size();i++) {
                         sendNotification(newReminderList.get(i).getRemMessage(),newReminderList.get(i).getInvM_Id());
        }
      }
        // Release the wake lock provided by the BroadcastReceiver.
        SampleAlarmReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
        // END_INCLUDE(service_onhandle)
    }
    // Post a notification indicating whether a doodle was found.
    private void sendNotification(String msg, int invM_id) {

        try {
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, ItemActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        notificationIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        data1=WebService.InvoiceDetailForExeedDiscount1(invM_id);
        notificationIntent.putExtra("invoiceList", data1);
        notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
               this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.invoice_alert))
        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
        .bigText(msg))
        .setContentText(msg);

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
        NOTIFICATION_ID++;}
         catch (IOException e) {

        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {

        }

    }

}
```

and itemActivity i am reading data like

```
public class ItemActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       final boolean customTitleSupported =
                requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.itemlist);
       if(customTitleSupported){
            getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE,R.layout.item);
       }
       InvoiceData1 invoiceList = (InvoiceData1) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("invoiceList");
}
```

its like when we come out of the application and click on second notification,its just blandly showing the invoice details of previous one,der is no call going on to fetch data for clicked on.

Comment: its behaving weirdly,when i am in app and click on notification it gives me accurate item detail in activity but when i come out of app and click on notification i gives me only one notification correct data,others data will be same has previous one..,http://pastie.org/10333705 ,i am getting perfect data,just outside d app it doesnt

Comment: outside the app if i click on first or any notification ,it wil show me proper data and again if i click on remaining notification it will show me the data of previously clicked,,this is just outside the app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` flag in your `PendingIntent` you must also implement `onNewIntenet()` method in `ItemActivity` to properly handle this launch mode. As per [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent(android.content.Intent)):

> This is called for activities that set launchMode to "singleTop" in
>   their package, or if a client used the FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP flag
>   when calling startActivity(Intent). In either case, when the activity
>   is re-launched while at the top of the activity stack instead of a new
>   instance of the activity being started, onNewIntent() will be called
>   on the existing instance with the Intent that was used to re-launch
>   it.
>
> An activity will always be paused before receiving a new intent, so
>   you can count on onResume() being called after this method.
>
> Note that getIntent() still returns the original Intent. You can use
>   setIntent(Intent) to update it to this new Intent.

so it should be sufficient to move some code from your `onResume()` and limit `onNewIntent()` implementation to single `setIntent()` call.

Comment: I added this particular method to my ItemAcivity ,even though i am getting the item id of clicked item,the screen displays me previous extra values :(         @Override
    public void onNewIntent(Intent intent){
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        setIntent(intent);
        InvoiceData1 invoiceList = (InvoiceData1) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("invoiceList");
        System.out.println("inv-new-" +invoiceList.getInvMId()) ;
    }

Comment: working out :) i was suppose to copy the same stuff of code present in OnCreate() ...,but its not that good idea na..,i need to write the same steps again or call d same twice just to reload the screen with new extras...not sure though..,thanks a lot .

Comment: you can make separate method and just call it from both places to avoid code duplication